# I removed the navbar in blogger blog, there is a way to reduce the space you have left?

Tags: blogger

I removed the navbar on my Blogger blog (blogspot). There are many guides online, but I can not find one that explains how to reduce the empty space left navbar. I think it requires action in the HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the css script `.navbar {display:"none";}`. I used that on my blog,

[image: used on the blog blog.falcondai.com]

See if that is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if I understand correctly, but there is a guide some time ago I used I for the same problem here [Empty space after removing the navigation bar of Blogger](http://www.mysensetechnology.com/2011/04/empty-space-after-removing-navigation.html) take a look, as I understand it with this guide will solve your problem, and let me know if everything went well.

Comment: Can you please summarise the page linked to here. If the page ever moves then your answer becomes worse than useless.